# Google App Engine Task Queues - nasty failure

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I'm developing an app for GAE and trying to use Task Queues. At present, I just have the thing running on my Windows box through GAE App Launcher but whenever I try to enqueue anything, the development 'server' crashes over and the log is full of nasty output.

```
taskqueue.add(url='/processWork', params={'key', myModel.key()})
```

I've tried running this in a transaction with other work so I'm pretty sure the work is being successfully enqueued.

However, shortly afterwards the development server crashes and the log is full of stuff like this:

```
ERROR    2011-02-06 17:04:23,289
__init__.py:395] global name 'true' is not defined Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 517, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)   File "C:\Projects\GAE\MyApp\main.py", line 114, in post
    activity.approved = true NameError: global name 'true' is not defined INFO     2011-02-06 17:04:23,309 dev_appserver.py:3317] "POST /processWork HTTP/1.1" 500 - WARNING  2011-02-06 17:04:23,309 taskqueue_stub.py:586] Task named "task1" on queue "default" failed with code 500; will retry in 30 seconds Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)   File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 311, in process_request
    self.shutdown_request(request)   File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 459, in shutdown_request
    request.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR) AttributeError: 'FakeConnection' object has no attribute 'shutdown' ERROR    2011-02-06 17:04:23,312 dev_appserver_main.py:494] Error encountered: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 488, in main
    http_server.serve_forever()
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3947, in serve_forever
    self.handle_request()
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3913, in handle_request
    self._handle_request_noblock()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 287, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.shutdown_request(request)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 459, in shutdown_request
    request.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)   AttributeError: 'FakeConnection' object has no attribute 'shutdown'   Now terminating.
---------------------------------------- Exception happened during processing of request from ('0.1.0.2', 80)
---------------------------------------- 2011-02-06 09:04:23 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Apologies - a reply below spotted the typo (true, not True). However, this crept in when trying to resolve the original problem though. If I fix the typo, the queued work completes but my server still falls over with this error in the log:

```
INFO     2011-02-06 17:50:32,882 dev_appserver.py:3317] "POST /processWork HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 311, in process_request
    self.shutdown_request(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 459, in shutdown_request
    request.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
AttributeError: 'FakeConnection' object has no attribute 'shutdown'
ERROR    2011-02-06 17:50:32,884 dev_appserver_main.py:494] Error encountered:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 488, in main
    http_server.serve_forever()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3947, in serve_forever
    self.handle_request()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3913, in handle_request
    self._handle_request_noblock()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 287, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.shutdown_request(request)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 459, in shutdown_request
    request.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

AttributeError: 'FakeConnection' object has no attribute 'shutdown'

Now terminating.
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('0.1.0.2', 80)
----------------------------------------
2011-02-06 09:50:32 (Process exited with code 1)
```

If I remove the call to taskqueue.add it works fine (without the queued work, of course). What is going wrong?

Comment: You should be using python 2.5 for appengine development. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/devenvironment.html I am not sure if this will impact your current problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py"
```

App Engine runs with Python 2.5 and you are using Python 2.7.

Comment: Really? Now I have a new problem? Where can I get Python 2.5 for Windows? I can find a .tar file on the Python site but it's just full of (seemingly random, to me) bits of source.

Comment: According to http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python, app engine uses 2.5.2, which you can get from http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.2/

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a simple typo:

```
__init__.py:395] global name 'true' is not defined 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 517, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)   
File "C:\Projects\GAE\MyApp\main.py", line 114, in post
    activity.approved = true NameError: global name 'true' is not defined
```

Go to `main.py` line 395 and change

```
 activity.approved = true
```

to

```
 activity.approved = True
```

(uppercase "T")

Comment: Oh dear - that's embarassing. However, that is a little typo that crept in after I experienced the problem. When I fix this - the queued task works but my server still crashes. See the update to the original question. Apologies for my mess up here.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's because you're using 2.7.  `shutdown()` was added in [2.6](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.BaseServer.shutdown).  You've got to run [2.5](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.5/).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually monkey patch in a fix in for this (required as of Python 2.7.1, pyOpenSSL 0.12 and Werkzeug 0.6.2):

```
### WARNING: Monkey patch in a fix to correct pyOpenSSL's
### incompatible ServerSocket implementation that accepts zero arguments
### for shutdown() instead of one. Fix is for:
### lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py:459's shutdown() call because that
### appears to be easier to quickly hack in versus patching
### pyOpenSSL. Again, don't use this for production, but it's great for
### testing.
def monkeyp_ssl_shutdown_request(self, request):
    try:
        request.shutdown()
    except socket.error:
        pass #some platforms may raise ENOTCONN here
    self.close_request(request)
from SocketServer import TCPServer
TCPServer.shutdown_request = monkeyp_ssl_shutdown_request
```

Not pretty, but it's better than an exception when someone closes an SSL TCP connection.

```
app.run(ssl_context='adhoc') # Now works
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason is that you fail to import the midule

```
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
```